# What is the optimal time between tree harvests?

Tags: skyforce-unite

In your base you can have two different types of trees; Money Trees, and Knowledge Trees. After some time you can harvest them for money and mile points respectively. But if you wait longer, the 'fruit' will ripen on the tree and yield greater rewards. Unfortunately if you wait too long, they will rot. Harvesting the rotten 'fruit' results in the minimum payout per tree.

Despite several attempts, I have not been able to pin down this time-frame. So how long is it from a harvest to the maximum yield of a tree? How long before your rewards rot?